# NService Bus throwing AnException While Using Castle Windsor

Tags: windows-services, hosting, nservicebus

```
static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
   {
       return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       .UseWindowsService()
       .UseNServiceBus(ctx =>
       {
           var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("bindingName");


           var containerSettings = endpointConfiguration.UseContainer(new WindsorServiceProviderFactory());
           containerSettings.ConfigureContainer(c => ConfigureCastleWindsor(c));

           endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo("error");
           endpointConfiguration.AuditProcessedMessagesTo("audit");
           endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();

           return endpointConfiguration;
       });


   }

   private static IWindsorContainer ConfigureCastleWindsor(IWindsorContainer c)
   {
       return c.Register(Component.For<DbStore>()
                                          .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("Connection", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["name"].ConnectionString))
                                          .LifeStyle.PerThread,
                        Component.For<IManageUnitsOfWork>().ImplementedBy<LinqUnitOfWork>().LifestyleTransient(),
                        Component.For<IMapper>().UsingFactoryMethod(x => new Mapper(ContractAutoMapper.Start())).LifestyleSingleton());
   }
```

I am referencing Nservice Bus document link (https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/dependency-injection/castlewindsor) to implement third part castle Windsor as DI in Nservice Bus 7.2.3 + NServiceBus.Extensions.Hosting .

Packages Information :

1. Host Window Service packages - NServiceBus.Extensions.Hosting.1.0.1
2. NServiceBus.Extensions.DependencyInjection (1.0.1)
3. Castle.Core (4.2.0)
4. Castle.Windsor (4.1.1)
5. Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection (3.0.0)
6. NServiceBus.CastleWindsor (7.0.0)

**NOTE: Third-party Castle Windsor with the internally managed mode**

**Error Information:** An internally managed container has already been configured using 'EndpointConfiguration.UseContainer'. It is not possible to use both an internally managed container and an externally managed container.

**Stack Trace:**    `NServiceBus.ContainerComponent.InitializeWithExternallyManagedContainer(IConfigureComponents configureComponents)
   at NServiceBus.EndpointCreator.CreateWithExternallyManagedContainer(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, IConfigureComponents configureComponents)
   at NServiceBus.HostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<UseNServiceBus>b__0(HostBuilderContext ctx, IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at Report.Program.Main(String[] args)`

**I am not using any external manager mode but still, I am running with this error,  could you please let us know how do we use third-party Castle Windsor as DI**.

Answer (score 0):

The error message states what the issue is. When using a custom container using `NServiceBus.Extensions.Hosting` package, you'll need to do so before and outside of the `UseNServiceBus` extension method. Here's a working snippet:

```
static IHostBuilder CreateHost()
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .UseServiceProviderFactory(context => new WindsorServiceProviderFactory())
        .ConfigureContainer<WindsorContainer>((ctx, container) =>
        {
            container.Register(Component.For<MyService>());  // <- Windsor registrations can go here.
        })
        .UseNServiceBus(nsb =>
        {
            //Don't apply the custom container here.
            var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("Samples.Castle");
            endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<LearningTransport>();

            return endpointConfiguration;
        });
}
```